# Integrating $\int \log(\tan(2x)) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Looking online I see that people are integrating $\int \tan(2x)dx$ by replacing $\tan(2x)$ with $\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)}$ and then using $u$-substitution for $2x$. Why can you not simply use $u=2x$ and then integrate $\frac12\int \tan(u)du$?

Comment: If you see that people do X, that does not mean that they can't do Y.

Comment: the methods are basically identical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's perfectly fine as long as you can find an antiderivative.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, your answer should be $\frac 12 \ln|\sec 2x| +C$.